# PHP Ampqlib Consumer Dies: Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 1 bytes

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

OK this is part of a Symfony2 Commandline script.  While the script is waiting it dies with this Exception.

```
[PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException]
    Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 1 bytes
```

I have searched google and found mention of heartbeat and set_time_out, but when I have tried to set in the constructor, but instead when I change it from the defaults it dies faster.

This is how my script is setup. for the Amqplib aspect of it.

```
    // Get the configuration options for RabbitMQ
        $queueConfig = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer()->getParameter("rabbit_mq");

    /**
     * Callback function for RabbitMQ
     * Everything in the callback function must remain in the call back function.
     */
    $callback = function($msg)
    {
      $msgObj = json_decode($msg->body, true);
      print_r($msgObj);
    };

    $connection = new AMQPConnection(
        $queueConfig['response']['host'],
        $queueConfig['response']['port'],
        $queueConfig['response']['username'],
        $queueConfig['response']['password'],
        '/'
      );

    $channel = $connection->channel();

    $queueName = 'myQueueName';

    $channel->basic_consume($queueName, '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

    while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
        $channel->wait();
    }
```

This is from AMQPStreamConnection.php which has the constructor.  AMQPConnection extends AMQPStreamConnection

```
public function __construct($host, $port,
                            $user, $password,
                            $vhost="/",$insist=false,
                            $login_method="AMQPLAIN",
                            $login_response=null,
                            $locale="en_US",
                            $connection_timeout = 3,
                            $read_write_timeout = 3,
                            $context = null)
```

Thoughts on how to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this issue was that we were using Amazon's load balancer and it was killing our connection at a certain time interval.  What I did was hacked a while loop to restart the consumer when it failed.